# Angular Kendo Grid Column Tooltip

Tags: angular, kendo-grid

I'm using the following markup for rendering a tooltip when hovering over a cell:

```html
    <kendo-grid-column field="firstName" title="First Name">
        <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem>
            <span kendoTooltip title="{{ dataItem.firstName }}">
                {{ dataItem.firstName }}
            </span>
        </ng-template>
    </kendo-grid-column>
```

Is it possible to integrate this into a directive so that I can do this (so I don't have to repeat code):

```html
    <kendo-grid-column field="firstName" title="First Name" myGridCellToolTip></kendo-grid-column>
```

Jason

Answer (score 1):

Try to wrap your span with a `div` and put here the directive, like:

```
<kendo-grid-column field="firstName" title="First Name">
    <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem>
        <div kendoTooltip>
            <span title="{{ dataItem.firstName }}">
               {{ dataItem.firstName }}
            </span>
        </div>
    </ng-template>
</kendo-grid-column>
```

Answer (score 1):

Both approaches are valid, but rendering multiple TooltipDirectives isn't recommended and as such, one should be used as demonstrated in the following knowledge base article:

https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/knowledge-base/show-grid-cells-content/

This will also avoid rendering multiple cell templates, which will increase performance in the long run.